# How to Get Count of variable in JSON Response Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have this json response:

[image: JSON Response]

How to get count of "members", i tried this in view:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($datas as $post)
    <tr
        <td scope="row">{{ sizeof($post ->json-> members) }}</td>d>
    </tr>
   @endforeach
</tbody>
```

But i got this error:

```
ErrorException
sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\firstapp\resources\views\s1.blade.php)
```

Any Kind of Help Please?

Comment: `members` is an object, not an array. You may have an issue when you build your array.

Comment: I'm not a Laravel dev but I mean it should be `$post -> 0-> json-> members`, isn't?

Comment: `members` is not an array in your data structure, but an object. A StdClass object only be the looks of it, so it won't have `Countable` implemented. You could use `get_object_vars` to get the properties of that object as an array, and then count those. (Not sure if that will work directly inside the template though.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution, i use this in view:

```
@foreach ($datas as $post)
 <tr>
   <td scope="row">{{ count((explode(',', json_encode($post->json->members)))) }</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

```
count(json_decode($post[0]->json->members, true));
```

My bad. Sorry;
Here solution
count(json_decode(json_encode($post[0]->json->members), true));

Comment: I got Error
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\firstapp\resources\views\s1.blade.php)

Comment: That makes no sense. `json_decode` wants a string as first parameter; the `members` property does _not_ contain a string, according to the shown debug output.